# Fisher Yates shuffle 1 number shown

Tags: javascript, algorithm, shuffle

I am using the Fisher Yates Shuffle and gone through the little tutorial, I can see that you can randomize an order such as 4,1,3,2,6,7,5 etc... but I want to find out how to have only 1 number shown. There could be a submit button and when I press submit a random number between 1 to 7 is shown.
That number is then put aside so when I hit submit again there will be a 100% chance I wont see that number again.
So basically I can press submit 7 times and the 8th time nothing will happen.
this was the Javascript i was using:

```
    <script>
Array.prototype.shuffle = function(){
  var i = this.length, j, temp;
while(--i > 0) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
    temp = this[j];
    this[j] = this[i];
    this[i] = temp;
    }
    return this;
}
var arr = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'];
var result = arr.shuffle();

document.write(result);
</script>
```

I have googled this with no success,
Many thanks.

Comment: Where is this submit being done? Do you mean actually submitting the page?

Comment: Shuffle the array and then use [`Array.prototype.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) or [`Array.prototype.shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift). Both remove the returned value from the array until the array is empty.

Comment: The submitting is being done on the main page and I want the single random number to be displayed under submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation of it that I have used.

```
function fisherYates ( myArray,stop_count ) {
  var i = myArray.length;
  if ( i == 0 ) return false;
  var c = 0;
  while ( --i ) {
     var j = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( i + 1 ) );
     var tempi = myArray[i];
     var tempj = myArray[j];
     myArray[i] = tempj;
     myArray[j] = tempi;
     c++;
     if(c == stop_count)return;
   }
}
```

You can call this with :

```
fisherYates(arr,Math.min(nr_items, selectionSize));
```

---

Note that

```
 var tempi = myArray[i];
 var tempj = myArray[j];
 myArray[i] = tempj;
 myArray[j] = tempi;
```

is a dumber version of:

```
 var temp = myArray[i];
 myArray[i] = myArray[j];
 myArray[j] = temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could print a particular position within the array, because it's randomised each time- isn't it? So, you could create a variable with that position, and then print the variable. E.g.

```
var finalResult = arr[2]; //you can have any position you want
document.write(finalResult);
```

That should work for you.